# Django put firstname into form

Tags: python, django, reference, foreign-keys

I have a working form and I like to add my logged in user's first name into my form. I made is with the username, but I can't find a solutions for first name. I know the user_firsname is not working. I'm new to Django :)

**models.py**

```
class Stressz_teszt(models.Model):

def __str__(self):
    return self.stressz_name

    user_name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    user_firstname = models.ForeignKey(User.firsname, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1) 
    stressz_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Comment: You already have a Foreign Key to user in the table no need to store their first name in the table then. It is redundant, you would need to update it every time user table is updated, etc. It is simply not worth it, not efficient and not needed. For getting the first name from an instance of `Stressz_teszt` you can simply write `stressz_teszt_instance.user_name.first_name`. You can similarly access other fields of the user this way.

Comment: if you want to add new properties to the standart User model, for instance, first name and last name, then you have to extend it, look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model